# Laravel how to create a validation rule to allow only a certain value to be chosen based on previous choice

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm working on a reduxForm in Laravel and have created some rules in my Request file. Most of them are pretty simple but there is one specific rule I need to add and I don't quite know how.

There is a toggle switch, and then later in the form there is a dropdown with a list of choices. What I need to do is to make sure that if the aforementioned toggle switch is set to ON, only allow a certain value to be chosen in the dropdown.

```
<SelectBox layout="inline" {...user_role}>
    <option value={ null }>-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="1">Role 1</option>
    <option value="2">Role 2</option>
</SelectBox>
```

This is the select box. If the toggle switch is on, the form should only submit when Role 2 is chosen. If the toggle switch is off, then either role can be chosen.

So far, the rule is as follows:

```
'user_role' => 'required'
```

which is fine, as it is required, but I need to expand it to basically say 'It can only be Role 2 if this toggle is True'

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you take a look at custom validation rules? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I considered it, but I wondered if there was a built in way to do it using the Laravel validation rules to be honest